# Get attribute using annotation value

Tags: java, annotations

I want to use the method *execute()* of the following class:

```
public class Parser {
    @Header("header1")
    private String attribute1;

    @Header("header2")
    private String attribute2;

    @Header("header3")
    private String attribute3;

    @Header("header4")
    private String attribute4;

    public String execute(String headerValue) {
        //Execute
    }
}
```

What I want this method to achieve is matching the *headerValue* parameter with one in the list of *@Header* annotations, and returning the value of the respective attribute. For example, if I call *execute("header3")*, it should return the value of *attribute3*

How can I achieve this? Or is it a better way to code this requirement?

Comment: I was expecting to get something cleaner with this. Apparently that's not the case. Would you care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use a map for this? You'd need one anyways in order to store the mapping of the annotation parameter value to the field but if you can do this without reflection it should be easier to code and to maintain.

What I mean is:

```
Map<String, String> attributes; //initialized

attributes.put("header1", value1);
...
```

In `execute()` you then just access the map.

You could improve this using an enum, e.g. in order to restrict the number of possible values.

Something like this:

```
enum HeaderType {
  HEADER1,
  HEADER2,
  ...
}

private Map<HeaderType, String> headerAttribs = ...;

void setAttrib( HeaderType type, String value ) {
  headerAttribs.put(type, value);
}

String getAttrib( HeaderType type ) {
  return headerAttribs.get(type);
}

public String execute(HeaderType type ) {
    //Execute
}
```

If you need to use a string for the header type you could consider employing an additional map string->header type to look up the correct type first.

Alternatively you could use a switch statement which since Java 7 should work with strings as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String execute(String headerValue) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
  for(Field field:this.getClass().getFields()) {
    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Header.class)) {
            Header annotation = field.getAnnotation(Header.class); 

            String name = annotation.value(); 
            if(name.equals(headerValue)) {
            Object val = this.getClass().getField(name).get(this);
            return (String) val;
            }
            }
    }    
    return null;
}
```

There are a couple of exception to handle in line:

Object val = this.getClass().getField(name).get(this);

You can return null for that exception if you don't want to throw it from this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
This may help you


     Field f[]= Parser.class.getDeclaredFields();
     for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {

     Annotation annotation[]= f[i].getAnnotations();
     for (int j=0;j<annotation.length;j++){

     Class<Annotation> type = (Class<Annotation>) annotation[j].annotationType();               

        for (Method method : type.getDeclaredMethods()) {

            if(method.getName() .equals(headerValue))
            {
            String name=f[i].getName();
           return name;
            }
        }

     }
     }
```

Parser.class.getDeclaredFields() will include private fields also.